# How to combine 2 javascript/jquery functions in a Wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, plugins

When it comes to JavaScript/jQuery, I'm still a bit of a newbie.

I've currently got a donation form with an html list in WordPress (plugin). The first 3 options are just fixed options (5 euro, 10 euro, 15 euro), but the last `li` option is a "open" option. When the last `li` is clicked, a hidden input field shows up where a user could type in a different value.

With jQuery I need these 2 functions:

The first one is to set `li` to active when it is clicked. When a specific `li` is active, a hidden input field will be visible.

The second one is to delete the first x character and the last x characters of the words inside the `li`.

These are the jQuery codes I'm currently using

This one for the active li:

```
$(".donate-box ul li").click(function(){
   if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $("li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
   }
});
```

This one for the characters:

```
$('.donate-box ul li').text(function (i,t) {
   return t.slice(0, -72);
});
$('.donate-box ul li').each(function() {
   var $th = $(this);
   $th.text( $th.text().substr(99) );
});
```

The html : This is for the list options

```
<ul id="form_624_field_2" label="" class="" required=""> 
    <li>€ 5,00</li> 
    <li>€ 10,00</li> 
    <li>€ 15,00</li> 
    <li>Anders </li> 
</ul>
```

This is for the open option, which opens when "anders" is active

```
<p id="rfmp_open_amount_624" style="display:none;"> 
   <label>Bedrag <span style="color:red;">*</span><br> 
       <span class="rfmp_currency_624">€</span> 
       <input type="number" step="any" value="" onchange="mollie_forms_624_totals();" name="rfmp_amount_624"> 
   </label> 
   <input type="hidden" id="rfmp_open_amount_required_624" value="0">
</p>
```

The both work separately, but when I add the second code (for the characters), the first one stops working properly. The `li` still gets active when clicked, but the hidden input field isn't showing up anymore. So something goes wrong.

Anybody that knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: any console error ?

Comment: create it a code snippet or js fiddle

Comment: @Kevin Yes 1 : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null
    at mollie_forms_recurring_methods_624 ((index):454)", but from what i can see, the error has nothing to do with this problem

Comment: @Sander I didn't understand the character part. what should it be? what is `$th.text( $th.text().substr(99) );` used for? please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to solve your problem by this fiddle(reformatting some HTML), But won't understand your character part.
Hope it solve your problem.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

var li_grp = $(".donate-box ul li")

li_grp.text(function (i,t) {
   return t.slice(1, -1);
});
li_grp.each(function() {
   var $th = $(this);
   $th.text( $th.text().substr(0) );
});
li_grp.click(function(){
  //alert('ss')
   if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(".donate-box ul li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
   }
   if($(this).hasClass('popup-hidden')){
      $('#rfmp_open_amount_624').show()
   }else{
      $('#rfmp_open_amount_624').hide()
   }
});
});
```

```css
.active{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="donate-box">
<ul id="form_624_field_2" label="" class="" required=""> 
    <li>€ 5,00</li> 
    <li>€ 10,00</li> 
    <li>€ 15,00</li> 
    <li class="popup-hidden">Anders </li> 
</ul>
</div>
<p id="rfmp_open_amount_624" style="display:none;"> 
   <label>Bedrag <span style="color:red;">*</span><br> 
       <span class="rfmp_currency_624">€</span> 
       <input type="number" step="any" value="" onchange="mollie_forms_624_totals();" name="rfmp_amount_624"> 
   </label> 
   <input type="hidden" id="rfmp_open_amount_required_624" value="0">
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Only problem that i'm facing right now, is there any way i can edit the HTML from the Wordpress Plugin? Without just editing the regular code, cause that will be overriden when there is an update...

Edit : There character part is to delete some white spaces before and after the values inside the li, the plugin auto added some white spaces which i couldnt delete inside the html itself.

Comment: What the thing you want to edit? code or add classes? if you edit the code, you'll lose those when the plugin gets updated. I hope the above snippet will help you to remove the spaces too!.

Comment: Mark as answer, if it helps.